# How to pass parameters to ARM assembly language?

Tags: assembly, arm, disassembly

I have the following assembly language program for A76 core. As you can see that the value I am loading to X0 is hard coded. How can I pass parameters and run the code in a loop for this program:

```
EXPORT tlb_ram_data_register_18_1
tlb_ram_data_register_18 PROC
;   B asm_Switch2NonSecure  
;   B EL1_to_EL3_Switch
LDR X0, =0x000000001800009B
SYS #6, c15, c0, #0, X0
DSB SY
ISB
MRS X0, S3_6_c15_c0_1 ; Move ILData0 register to X1
RET 
ENDP
```

The value for X0 (0x000000001800009B) is the encoding address of the register which contains variables like cache way and indices. I have to change the way and indices in loop to read different contents of this register from a C code like below:

```
for(way0 = 0x0;way0 <= 0xFF ; way0++)
{
    I0_W0 = tlb_ram_data_register_18_1(way0);
}
```

One more question is: If I read X0 like I am doing in the assembly code and return from the function, then will that value go to I0_W0?

Answer (score 2):

technically it is compiler specific, but for ARM a number of them conform to the same ABI.  But you can just ask the compiler and it will give you the correct answer.  Write a program test program

```
extern unsigned int tlb_ram_data_register_18_1 ( unsigned int );
unsigned int fun ( void )
{
    unsigned int way0;

    for(way0 = 0x0;way0 <= 0xFF ; way0++)
    {
        tlb_ram_data_register_18_1(way0);
    }
    return(5);
}
```

for the moment I am building an aarch64 compiler but for now here is what arm looks like, you will see something similar with any target.

I am using a current version of gcc

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   4:   e3a04000    mov r4, #0
   8:   e1a00004    mov r0, r4
   c:   e2844001    add r4, r4, #1
  10:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <tlb_ram_data_register_18_1>
  14:   e3540c01    cmp r4, #256    ; 0x100
  18:   1afffffa    bne 8 <fun+0x8>
  1c:   e3a00005    mov r0, #5
  20:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
  24:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

not so obvious but r0 is being used as the parameter to the function

also note r0 is used for the return value

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int x )
{
    return(x+1);
}


00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

r0 is both the first/only parameter and is also used for the return.

ahh I do have an aarch64 gcc handy

```
0000000000000000 <fun>:
   0:   11000400    add w0, w0, #0x1
   4:   d65f03c0    ret
```

w0 on the way and on the way out.  you can try this again with a 64bit parameter and see if that changes.

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot old_timer. Let me work on your inputs, will update you soon.

Comment: Technically, any new version of the compiler it is fair game to change the calling convention, so you should always have at least a little concern.  Likewise other compilers for the same target.  At the same time though a number of the major architectures have settled into either a third party standard or their own for a target.  Point is there is no governing body that dictates that any old compiler has to conform to something.  There are well written recommendations but the authors of the compiler are free to do whatever they choose.

Comment: For the compiler to be remotely useful though they need to be consistent so simple experiments like the above are the quickest way so long as you make the example in a way that mimics the call, there can be subtle things you dont know that will trip this up.  Best to both find the documented convention if possible and to clarify the language in there which is often confusing, compare it to what the compiler is actually doing, between the two lies the answer.